# Nested table data retrieval

Tags: oracle10g

I have simillar table like one below with nested table column :

```
create type hobbies_tab as table of varchar2(20);

create table Person(id Number,name varchar2(20),hobbies hobbies_tab) NESTED TABLE HOBBIES STORE AS TAB_HOBBIES;

insert into person values(2,'Sita',hobbies_tab('dancing','books'));

insert into person values(1,'Palash',hobbies_tab('Cricket','football'));

insert into person values(3,'sham',hobbies_tab('Cricket','dancing'));
```

I want to select persons who have 'dancing' as one of their hobbies , I don't know what to write in where clause of select query.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.name
    from person p, table(p.hobbies) h
        where h.column_value = 'dancing';
```

Or if the value can be Dancing/DANCING/Riverdancing the where clause could be:

```
where lower(h.column_value) like '%dancing%'
```